# Not a valid identifier 'index,index.html' AEM 6.2

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6

I get that error after deploying my project. Does anyone know how to fix it?

This appears in `http://localhost:4502/` so, the `damadmin`, `crx/de`, `system/console/*` works good.

Complete error:

```
Not a valid identifier 'index,index.html'

Cannot serve request to / in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid identifier 'index,index.html'
```

Comment: There could be a lot of possibilities. Do you have Sling mappings? (/etc/map)

Comment: Thanks but I don't have mappings, so, I deleted crx-quickstart folder, that fixed the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue where people have misconfigured the Index Resources section of the Apache Sling GET Servlet.

Visit /system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Look at the Index Resources field.

If you have it like [ "index","index.html" ] then you've set it up wrong and will get this error in your error log

Instead they should be separate entries one above the other.
So make the first entry "index"
Then hit the plus sign on the right and add "index.html" as the next entry and hit save at the bottom.

People read the text below the configuration element too literally.  It says "The default value is [ "index", "index.html" ]". So instead of reading that as a multi-value field with index and index.html as two values.  They simply copy and paste it into the field and save.  This creates that issue you've described.

Please please please do not do what e-israel suggests and delete your AEM installation by deleting the crx-quickstart folder.  This is like formatting your drive or the linux equivalent of an `rm -rf` on your application directory.  Terrifying suggestion and wanted to mention it for any poor person who dared follow it.